# Inserting data into xml file

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, ado

I want to update connection string into xml file whenever new customer is registered with the website with its details in asp.net core 3.1

My connection string format is

```
<ConnectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnectionString1" connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb1;uid=myUser1;password=myPass;" />
    <add name="myConnectionString2" connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb2;uid=myUser2;password=myPass;" />
</ConnectionStrings>
```

I want to achieve this using c# code so on registration this data will automatically  updated in xml file

Comment: "My connection string format is"... I think you forgot something. Also, please post the relevant code. Hard to help you when we don't know what you're working with.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb: It was there. It just wasn't formatted in code, which makes it look like HTML, and raw HTML for the most part is not accepted in posts here. I've fixed the formatting.

Comment: have a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.connectionstringssection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

You can edit your existing XML as follows.

```
// Loads XML from file.
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\yourFile.xml");

// Get a list of all <ConnectionStrings> nodes.
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/ConnectionStrings");

// Loop through each found node.
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
   // Search for the 'connectionString' attribute into the node.
   XmlAttribute attrib = node.Attributes["connectionString"];

   if (attrib != null)
   {
      // If the attribute could be found then you might want to get its value.
      string currentValue = attrib.Value;    
      // Or do some stuff with the value. E.g: Set a new value based on the old one.
      attrib.Value = currentValue + "your modification here";
   }
}

// Finally you might want to save the document in other location.
doc.Save(@"C:\yourNewFile.xml";
```

**EDIT:** As per requested you can add a new connection string element to your connection strings section as follows. (Not tested. It could require some adjustments)

```
using System.Configuration;

   // Create a connection string element and add it to
   // the connection strings section.
   private bool CreateConnString(string name, string connString, string uId, string password)
   {
     try
     {
        // Get the application configuration file.
        System.Configuration.Configuration config =
               ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
               ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        // Get the current connection strings count.
        int connStrCnt = 
           ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Count;

        // Create a connection string element and
        // save it to the configuration file.

        // In your case 'connString' parameter should be 
        // something like "server=localhost;database=myDb1;"
        ConnectionStringSettings csSettings =
               new ConnectionStringSettings(name, connString +
               "uid=" + uId + ";password=" + password + ";");

        // Get the connection strings section.
        ConnectionStringsSection csSection =
           config.ConnectionStrings;

        // Add the new element.
        csSection.ConnectionStrings.Add(csSettings);

        // Save the configuration file.
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        return true;
      }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        return false;
     }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response But dear I want to make some method

like 
public void CreateConnString(string name, string connString, string uId, string password)

and every time when new customer will add to system I will make new database and after  creating database I will call this method and 
I have to add new line for every customer 

Please let me know