# Dynamic Connection String in xml filr using asp net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-c++

I want to create one xml file and add the new connection string every time when new customer is added to the system

Can anyone plz let me know how to achieve this I am new to this platform

Code Snipet is below

```
<ConnectionStrings>
    <Client1 ClineID=”101” DBpath=""  connectinString="server=SEPL162\MSSQLSERVER14; database=185_HPHDS_18112019; User id=sa; Password=sa@123;">
    <Client2 ClineID=”102” DBpath=""  connectinString="server=SEPL162\MSSQLSERVER14; database=185_HPHDS_18112019; User id=sa; Password=sa@123;">
</ConnectionStrings>
```

Comment: this link maybe help you : https://dzone.com/articles/dynamic-connection-string-in-net-core

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inserting data into xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61775396/inserting-data-into-xml-file)